# ReactJS typescript error Parameter props implicitly has 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Following, and adapting the tutorial [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), I've hit a snag when trying to define a function to render some HTML.

```
function Toolbar(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>Refresh</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This errors in Typescript, because props is not defined.  I understand why I'm getting the error, but what I'm missing is what type should `props` be?

I believe I should then be able to use this inside another component like this:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar onClick={() => alert('hello world')}>Test</Toolbar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the `props` is just whatever I specify.  This would seem to be borne out [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html): although that link doesn't mention typescript.  So, my question is: how does this feature (that of passing properties into a function or class) work with typescript when, by definition, you don't know what you're passing through?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should define an interface for the props.

```
interface Props {
   onClick: () => void;
}

function Toolbar(props: Props) {
   return (
       <div>
           <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>Refresh</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

I also like to define my functional components as an arrow function. And you can use the FC (Functional Component) type definition with the Props generic type. This way you can deconstruct your properties right away.

```
const Toolbar: React.FC<Props> = ({onClick}) => {
   return (
       <div>
           <button onClick={() => onClick()}>Refresh</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: What if the `props` is just a dictionary of attribute? e.g. `{width, height, id}`  Is there a type for this?

Comment: @Anthony Kong, you can use them in the same way. Setup an interface with the mentioned property names and their corresponding types.
interface Props {
 width: number,
 heights: number,
 id: string
}